# How to pass in arguments in flutter when user input URL address (using auto_route)

Tags: flutter, dart, routes

My app uses flutter with auto_router 0.6.9 package, and I want **user to be able to type in a web address http://localhost/#/book/123 and be able to access book 123 and display book123, their name, and email if they are logged in**. I had figured out the routing part with auto_router but when the user put the address directly into the browser, the arguments should be passed into the page are null.

**I was wondering is there a way to parse the url and pass in the arguments required before displaying the page. Thanks for any help or hints!**

My router.dart page:

```
@MaterialAutoRouter(
  routes: <AutoRoute>[
    // some other pages...
    MaterialRoute(path: "/book/:id", page: MultiProvider),
  ],
)
class $ModularRouter {}
```

The router.gr.dart generated for multiprovider arguments class is:

```
/// MultiProvider arguments holder class
class MultiProviderArguments {
  final Key key;
  final List<SingleChildWidget> providers;
  final Widget child;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext, Widget) builder;
  MultiProviderArguments(
      {this.key, @required this.providers, this.child, this.builder});
}
```

My book menu page contains a navigation:
(this is an example of how I normally call the BookPage in another page)

```
child: GestureDetector(
onTap: () => ExtendedNavigator.of(context).push(
    Routes.multiProvider(id: book[index].bookID),
    arguments: MultiProviderArguments(
    providers: [
        Provider<UserData>.value(
            value: userdata,
        ),
        Provider<List<BookInfo>>.value(
            value: book,
        ),
    ],
    child: BookPage(
        bookId: book[index].bookID,
        name: userdata.userName,
        email: userdata.email,
    ),
    ),
),
...
```

And BookPage takes in 3 arguments bookId, name and email:

```
class BookPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String bookId;
  final String name;
  final String email;

  BookPage({
    this.bookId,
    this.name,
    this.email,
  });
...
}

...

class _BookPageState extends State<BookPage> {
    ...
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final currentUser = Provider.of<UserData>(context, listen: false);
        final currentBook = Provider.of<List<BookInfo>>(context, listen: false);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had figured out a Band-Aid solution (which I don't consider to be permanent):

I had abandoned using auto-route which I have no idea how to parse the url and use onGenerateRoute instead:

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
  final settingsUri = Uri.parse(settings.name);
  final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

  if (user == null) {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          return LogInPage();
        }
    );
  } else {
    // Handle '/'
    if (settingsUri.pathSegments.length == 0) {
      return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return PageWrapper(false, bookid);
          }
      );
    }

    // Handle '/book/:id'
    if (settingsUri.pathSegments.length == 2) {
      if (settingsUri.pathSegments.first != 'book') {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) {
              return UnknownPage();
            }
        );
      }

      final bookid = settingsUri.pathSegments.elementAt(1);
      if (bookid == null) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return UnknownPage();
          }
        );
      }

      return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return PageWrapper(false, bookid);
          }
      );
    }
  }
  //Handle other unknown Routes
  return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return UnknownPage();
      }
  );
}
```

The PageWrapper authenticates user, build providers, and call BookPage class, I put the code in a place where userData providers had already been initialized:

```
if (this.needRedirect == true) {
  return Scaffold(
    ...
    body: FutureBuilder(
        future: Future.wait([userData]),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return MultiProvider(
              providers: [
                //initialize using streamproviders
                ...
              ],
              child: BookPage(
                bookId: book[index].bookID,
                name: userdata.userName,
                email: userdata.email,
              ),
          );
        }),
  );
}
else {...}
```

The short answer is I had called the WrapperPage in onGenerateRoutes because the providers are not initialized in main.dart, but they are initialized in WrapperPage. Then I put the redirect code after provider initialization in WrapperPage and called BookPage.

This method had caused other bugs, but it had achieved its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

1. in auto_router add path

```dart
AutoRoute(page: ..., path: '/mypage/:id'),
```

2. and add @PathParam to page constructor

```dart
const MyPage({
    super.key,
    @PathParam('id') this.id });
```

3. call page with param

```dart
context.push(MaPageRoute(id: 42),
```